# Given a matrix $A$ find $A^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A=$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2\\ 
    0 & 1  
    \end{bmatrix} $

Find $A^n$.

**My input:**

$A^2= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2\\ 
    0 & 1  
    \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2\\ 
    0 & 1  
    \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 4\\ 
    0 & 1  
    \end{bmatrix} $

$A^3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 6\\ 
    0 & 1  
    \end{bmatrix} $
......

$A^n = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2n\\ 
    0 & 1  
    \end{bmatrix} $

This was very basic approach. I want to know if there is any other way a smart trick or something to solve this problem ?

Comment: You could first propose $A^n = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2n\\ 
    0 & 1  
    \end{bmatrix}$ from observation, then use induction I guess.

Comment: What you have done is a very good way to *discover* the answer. Now, you ought to *prove* the answer, and that can be done by Mathematical Induction.

Comment: But, @chítrungchâu, this matrix can't be diagonalized.

Comment: Thank you karn and gerry

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form . Compute the power of the sum of a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix should be easy

Comment: The matrix in question reminds me of a Fibonacci type:   $F_{n+1}=F_{n-1}+2F_n$. With what you have done you can connect the matrix method (which didn't seem possible due to diagonalisation issue) and the General formula.

Comment: Take into account that $A=I+2N$, where $N$ is zero everywhere except for the top right corner entry. Since $N^2=0$, then $A^n=(I+2N)^n=I^n+2nN+\text{ terms in which }N\text{ has higher degree}= I+2nN$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this too
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A=I_2+B$$
And B is a nilpotent matrix $\implies B^2=0$
$$A^n=(I_2+B)^n$$
Use  binomial theorem

Comment: Nice. Thank you

Comment: @Damn1o1 yw with binomilal identity you get the result directly since $B^n=0$ for $n \ge 3$

Answer (score 8):

What you did *was* the smart approach. That is, you computed the first few terms of the sequence $(A^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and you noticed a patern. The only thing that remains to be done is to prove that the pattern is real, but that's easy. Obviously,$$A^1=A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$and$$A^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&2n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\implies A^{n+1}=A.\begin{pmatrix}1&2n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&2(n+1)\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 4):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)^2$ so for any entire function $f$ we have
$$f(A) = f(1)P + f'(1)Q$$
for some $P, Q$ polynomials in $A$.

Plugging in $f \equiv 1$ and $f(x) = x$ we get $P = I$ and $Q = A-I$.

Therefore for $f(x) = x^n$ we have

$$A^n = 1^n\cdot I + n1^{n-1}\cdot (A-I) = I + n(A-I) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2n \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That's a really nice solution @mechanodroid. The use of the minimal polynomial is really a nice one! One can obviously use induction or binomial as done in the previous posts, but this one is an absolute beauty. Really nice one!